# ArgumentError in UsersController#new wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) for nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error:

[image]

I tried following along http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms because it is very close to something I am trying to create

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.contact_requests.build
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end

  private

    def user_params
      # strong_parameters, which requires us to tell Rails exactly which parameters
      # we want to accept in our controllers
      params.require(:users).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number, contact_requests_attributes: [:message])
      # params.require(:users).permit!
    end
end
```

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  has_many :contact_requests
  # validate the presence of the attributes
  validates(:first_name, presence: true)
  validates(:last_name, presence: true)
  validates(:email, presence: true)
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_requests

end

class ContactRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
end
```

form:

```
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title-container">Contact Us</div>
    <div class="title-caption">Reach us at (415)-911-9999</div>
    <%= form_for(@user, remote: true, id: "contact-form", class: "contact-input") do |f| %>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:first_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First name")%>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.text_field(:last_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Last name") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.email_field(:email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email") %>
          </div>
          <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
            <%= f.telephone_field(:phone_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone number") %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input-margin col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.fields_for :contact_requests do |builder| %>
              <%= builder.text_area(:message, class: "form-control contact-margin", rows: "8", placeholder: "Message...") %>
              <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit(class: "btn btn-xl") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Let me guess. You are using Rails 4.2.0 beta? And this error trace points to `lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:271:in `initialize'`?

Comment: @MarekLipka howd you know? Michael Hartl tutorial told me to do so!

Comment: Set your `arel` version in `Gemfile` to `'6.0.0.beta2'`.

Comment: @MarekLipka after your suggestions. I am not getting that error anymore. But I am getting another one =/ `Unpermitted parameter: contact_requests`